# Is there an important reason for why Google's Datastore and Firestore are so limited when it comes to querying?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, datastore

If I understand correctly, both Datastore and Firestore provide very limited options for querying substrings. Options, which I'd honestly would have expected to be available, like "LIKE" or "IN", seem not to be supported like they often are by Database Management Systems. Although a limited version of IN seems to be available in Firestore. Is there something I'm missing here? Fetching all entities of a kind to process them yourself server-side seems like a horrible way to deal with these limitations. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has a rather unusual performance guarantee: its query performance is completely independent of the number of documents that it has to consider. In its own terms: query performance is dependent on the size of the result set, not on the size of the collection. This means that if it takes 2s to retrieve 10 documents out of a collection of 1,000 documents, it will also take 2s to retrieve those 10 documents out of a collection of 1,000,000 documents, or even out of a collection of 1,000,000,000 documents.

Firestore only allows queries where it guarantee this performance. If a query type is now available on Firestore, it's because it can't meet the performance guarantee for that query type.

You will have to make a choice for yourself whether your app benefits more from the performance guarantee that Firestore makes, or from the additional query capabilities that another database may offer.

---

To learn more about trade-offs in NoSQL databases in general, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), and for Firestore specifically, watch the [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) series.